# Select all unlinked items in a nested list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
 <ul>
     <li><a ...>item 1</a></li>
     <li>item 2
          <ul>
              <li><a ...>item 2-a</a></li>
              <li><a ...>item 2-b</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a ...>item 3</a></li>
    <li>item 4
          <ul>
              <li><a ...>item 4-a</a></li>
              <li><a ...>item 4-b</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a ...>item 5</a></li>
    <li><a ...>item 6</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to add a class to 'item 2' and 'item 4' with jquery using `.has` but can't find a way.

---

I want to clarify my question:
I have a nested list with an unknown amount of items where some items are not linked. I want to add a class to all unliked items.

Comment: What you mean by _using '.has'_??

Comment: Was it your intent for the `<li>item 2</li>` to be the same as `<li>item 4</li>`? If so the closing `</li>` is in the wrong place in one of them.

Comment: Please show what you tried. This isn't a code writing service. The idea is to help fix your code

Comment: I corrected the wrong </li> in my example. My intention is to add the same class to all <li> without a link.

Comment: Please, clarify in the question itself, what "li" tags you are attempting to select and what constraints will always apply to where they are within the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only selecting for list items without anchors, as clarified in the questions comments.

```
var parentList = $('ul'); // something more specific is assumed.
parentList.children('li').children().not('a').parent().addClass('some-class');
```

Using "contains" makes the solution dependent on content, not structure. Using "eq" or similar "nth"-like functionality is assuming that the given example is the only structure, whereas I think it is planned as generated code that may extend to a much longer length, but will always keep the structure defined in the snippet.

Comment: That's perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: @zakaria-acharki [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40322709/3003133) uses CSS  pseudo-class selectors, which may preform better, but I have not tested this nor read up much on it. Both should work, the choice should be purely stylistic as the performance should only matter on **huge** lists.

Comment: This won't do anything different than a much simpler `$('li').has('ul')` unless there are other elements not shown

Comment: @charlietfl, I agree and that is basically what I had at first, but the questions constraints were clarified in it comments. I asked them to add the clarification into the question itself. You should bump @vadimb answer if you believe using `.has('ul')` is best, but I think my answer is want the poster wants.

Comment: @charlietfl, oh sorry, I did not see that you have your own improved version of that answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the class depending to the content of the `li` you could use `:contains` selector :

```
$( "li:contains('item 2')" ).addClass('X');
```

Or filter and check `text()` content :

```
$( "li" ).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text()==='item 4';
}).addClass('X');
```

If you want to add class using the `index`'s use `.eq()` like Robiseb's answer show.

**EDIT :**

> I don't know how many `<li>` without a link will be in the list. And I don't know what the text inside the `<li>` will be.

You could use :

```
$("li:not(:has(>a))").addClass('X');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("li:not(:has(>a))").addClass('X');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a ...>item 1</a></li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul>
      <li><a ...>item 2-a</a></li>
      <li><a ...>item 2-b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a ...>item 3</a></li>
  <li>item 4
    <ul>
      <li><a ...>item 4-a</a></li>
      <li><a ...>item 4-b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a ...>item 5</a></li>
  <li><a ...>item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know how many <li> without a link will be in the list. And I  don't know what the text inside the >li> will be.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.eq()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('li').eq(1).addClass('yourClass');
```

Be careful, `eq` starts to 0

Comment: better check what those indexes refer to, second one isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments you want to check if it has a sub `<ul>`

```
$('li').has('ul').addClass('has-children');
// OR
$('li:has(ul)').addClass('has-children');
```

Comment: Your idea is helpful for me. But my aim is to select all <li> in an nested list that have only text without a link (in my example item 2 and item 4).

Comment: Well that wasn't explained. You want the sub elements also?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  ul {color: #777777;}
  ul.items-list {color: #880000;}
  .your-class-name {color: #008800;}
</style>
<body>
 <ul class="items-list">
     <li><a>item 1</a></li>
     <li>item 2
          <ul>
              <li><a>item 2-a</a></li>
              <li><a>item 2-b</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>item 3</a></li>
    <li>item 4
          <ul>
              <li><a>item 4-a</a></li>
              <li><a>item 4-b</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>item 5</a></li>
    <li><a>item 6</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
<script>
    var $list = $('ul.items-list');
    $list.children('li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(4)').addClass('your-class-name');
</script>
```

Comment: will affect sub `<ul>` also

Comment: Right. If not intended, there should be a class or id identifier for each element. I updated the answer regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can select item by your content, using `:contains()` selector

For more details: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Example: http://jsbin.com/nutekaxora/edit?html,css,js,output

`$("li:contains('Item 1')").addClass('myClass');`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this, but use the "eq" method for this.

```
var first = $("ul").first();

$(first).find("li").eq(1).addClass("newClass"); /// This selects the second list item
$(first).find("li").eq(5).addClass("newClass"); // This selects the sixth list item
```

Here's a pen for this to show it in action.
http://codepen.io/raghavkanwal/pen/XjLjJM

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to detect all 'li' with 'ul' as a children?
https://jsfiddle.net/Ln3kt6ya/

May this example help you?

```
$('li').has('ul').addClass('error');
```