# add a class to a not linked title in a menu in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I use the following TS for a menu. All titles without content will not be linked. I would like to add a class to the no linked titles to format them in a special way. I got help to do that with jquery:
[Select all unlinked items in a nested list with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322634/select-all-unlinked-items-in-a-nested-list-with-jquery). Now I wonder whether it is also possible with TS only.

```
lib.Menu = HMENU
lib.Menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject.field = title
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.override.cObject =TEXT
            stdWrap.override.cObject {
                field = title
                typolink.parameter.field = uid
                if.isTrue.numRows {
                    table = tt_content
                    select.pidInList.field = uid                
                }       
            }
        }
    }
    2 < .1  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it by myself:

```
lib.Menu = HMENU
lib.Menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="xxx">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject.field = title
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.override.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.override.cObject {
                field = title
                typolink.parameter.field = uid
                if.isTrue.numRows {             
                    table = tt_content
                    select.pidInList.field = uid                
                }           
            }
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject = COA
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject {
                    if.isTrue.numRows {             
                        table = tt_content
                        select.pidInList.field = uid                
                    }
                10 = TEXT
                10.value = <li>|</li>
            }           
        }
    }
    2 < .1  
}
```

Comment: One problem remains: If I have a page with an external link and no content the title will not be linked.